# How can I execute tests on specific browser through Jenkins using choice parameters?

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, testng, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to perform testing on specific browser through Jenkins i.e. if I select firefox or chrome browser from dropdown and click on build to process further. How can I make it working. We are using in built automation framework.What if I maintain different testng.xml files as respective to browser. But again how can achieve it using same approach.

Let me know end to end best solution for it.

Thanks.

Comment: You are going to have to add some more explanation around the framework that you are already using. Ideally you would do what Shlomi mentioned below and parameterize the build. Your framework would then look at that property set by the job and use that to create the web driver configuration that you are after. You could also look into using a tool like selenium grid to handle running different browsers for your tests to run against. Jenkins has little to do with what browsers your tests are running against though. That config will live inside your test automation framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use build with parameters and select the browser you want from a select element.

Then, you set the browser you want it to be executed on to be a parameter inside your pipeline file instead of changing all the parameters like you are doing right now(I guess?) or using multiple builds.

If you could expand on what you currently have the way you are using it right now, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I would be glad if you provide the complete example as I am new to automation testing and Jenkins

Comment: Just paste what you currently have, or some of it... So I get the idea how you want it to work and I'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a parameter in jenkins where you need to develop your code to read that parameter.
This parameter is called Choice parameter under "MAVEN INFO PLUGIN CONFIGURATION" in general settings of project in jenkins.
Check on "This project is parameterized"
add name as "Browser" and choices as your browser names you want to specify like

```
IE
EDGE
CHROME
```

Above process will let you trigger tests using choice parameters but one more change needs to be done is at "Goals and options" under BUILD section.
Here please use (`test -DBrowser="$Browser"`) which lets you pass choice parameter value selected with Browser as key.

Try below code in your utilities to read browser type and so use driver type accordingly.

```
    String DriverType = System.getProperty("Browser"); 
if(DriverType.contains("IE")) { 
                  DriverType = "IE"; 
                                } else {
                                          DriverType ="Edge"; 
                                       }   return DriverType;
```